# onBackPress in IF ELSE statement doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android, if-statement, navigation-drawer, onbackpressed

I have a little trouble with  **public void onBackPressed()**. Everything in the **IF ELSE statement** works fine except the final ELSE. The final **ELSE statement** is suppose to **close the app** but it doesn't. Can anyone here help me fix this please?

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    } else if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        //returns previous webpage
        mWebView.goBack();

    }else if (count == 0) {
        //closes Fragment
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        HomeFragment homefragment = new HomeFragment();
        FragmentManager manager =getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(
                R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                homefragment,
                homefragment.getTag()).commit();
    } else {
        //Close app (Not working!!)
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a strong feeling the third if should be `else if (count != 0)`

Comment: @Shaishav I share that strong feeling. Move to the answer so you can be properly rewarded if that's it and I guess it is.

Comment: Yes same here but I think code need some improvement also if @Frances need. Seems pop back stack called but same time replacing current fragment with home. This seems either some smart logic or bug.

Comment: Try without the first and second (else) just have (if, if, if, else)

Comment: @Shaishav: I thought so too but it didn't work.

Comment: Is the activity derived from any other base class that may not be calling its `super.onBackPressed()`? What exactly happens when the backstack is empty (tried breakpoints?)?

Answer (score 0):

Use proper braces while using condition like

```
if(condition){

  } else {
     if(condition){

       } else {

    } 
 }
```

will not confuse you.

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                //returns previous webpage
                mWebView.goBack();

            } else {
                if (count == 0) {
                    //closes Fragment
                    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                    HomeFragment homefragment = new HomeFragment();
                    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(
                            R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                            homefragment,
                            homefragment.getTag()).commit();
                } else {
                    //Close app (Not working!!)
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. But still not closing app

Answer (score 0):

Since, you need to remove fragments from backstack only when the count is more than 0, modify your third if-else statement to reflect that:

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() { 

    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    } else if (mWebView.canGoBack()) { 
        //returns previous webpage 
        mWebView.goBack(); 

    }else if (count != 0) {  // change here
        //closes Fragment 
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        HomeFragment homefragment = new HomeFragment();
        FragmentManager manager =getSupportFragmentManager(); 
        manager.beginTransaction().replace( 
                R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                homefragment,
                homefragment.getTag()).commit();
    } else { 
        // probably working now
        super.onBackPressed(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: onBackPressed()  app now closes. but my fragment does not disappear and return my webview. It just closes the app. There's something wrong with that 3rd If statement.

Comment: @FrancesOkolo I think you need to check if the fragment with webview is in active of not and only then call `goBack` on it. Can check by checking the fragment name at the top of backstack

Answer (score 0):

Try this in last else block,

super.onBackPressed();
   finish();